# Opening ICS File Multiple Times Leading to Duplicate Meetings in Calendar

Tags: email-attachments, icalendar

I'm creating an ICS file with more than one events. However, Each time I'm opening this ICS file, events are getting added to my calendar creating duplicates meetings in my Outlook calendar. I want events to be added only when I open the file for the first time and if events are already there in the calendar, Outlook should simply ignore adding that event.

[Meetings imported twice when file is opened twice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTPGn.png)

When I'm using "METHOD: PUBLISH" in my ICS file containing multiple event and opening this file more than once then each time the meeting events are getting added to my Outlook calendar leading to duplicate meetings in the calendar.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
METHOD:PUBLISH
PRODID:-//calenderInvite//NONSGML v1.0//EN
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:john.doe@maill.com
ORGANIZER;CN="":MAILTO:peter.parker@mail.com
DESCRIPTION;LANGUAGE=en-US:
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<html> <head></head> <body>  Test Day 1 </body></html>
UID:Calendar_Event_599b59c7-3b70-4ea3-8e6f-2a4d1e586219_day_1
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-US:Test Day 1
DTSTART:20231205T090000Z
DTEND:20231205T093000Z
DTSTAMP:20231205T043203Z
PRIORITY:5
TRANSP:OPAQUE
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SEQUENCE:0
LOCATION;LANGUAGE=en-US:https://some.random.url.com
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:john.doe@maill.com
ORGANIZER;CN="":MAILTO:peter.parker@mail.com
DESCRIPTION;LANGUAGE=en-US:
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<html> <head></head> <body>  Test Day 2 </body></html>
UID:Calendar_Event_9c5de28b-f66c-446c-a25e-6fdcda58f221_day_2
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-US:Test Day 2
DTSTART:20231205T100000Z
DTEND:20231205T103000Z
DTSTAMP:20231205T043203Z
PRIORITY:5
TRANSP:OPAQUE
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SEQUENCE:0
LOCATION;LANGUAGE=en-US:https://some.random.url.com
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Also, When I'm using "METHOD: REQUEST" in my ICS file it's not adding duplicates but only the first event from the file is getting added to calendar and rest all events in the file are getting ignored.

Below file is same as above only "METHOD:PUBLISH" has changed to "METHOD:REQUEST".

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
METHOD:REQUEST
PRODID:-//calenderInvite//NONSGML v1.0//EN
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:john.doe@maill.com
ORGANIZER;CN="":MAILTO:peter.parker@mail.com
DESCRIPTION;LANGUAGE=en-US:
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<html> <head></head> <body>  Test Day 1 </body></html>
UID:Calendar_Event_599b59c7-3b70-4ea3-8e6f-2a4d1e586219_day_1
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-US:Test Day 1
DTSTART:20231205T090000Z
DTEND:20231205T093000Z
DTSTAMP:20231205T043203Z
PRIORITY:5
TRANSP:OPAQUE
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SEQUENCE:0
LOCATION;LANGUAGE=en-US:https://some.random.url.com
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:john.doe@maill.com
ORGANIZER;CN="":MAILTO:peter.parker@mail.com
DESCRIPTION;LANGUAGE=en-US:
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<html> <head></head> <body>  Test Day 2 </body></html>
UID:Calendar_Event_9c5de28b-f66c-446c-a25e-6fdcda58f221_day_2
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-US:Test Day 2
DTSTART:20231205T100000Z
DTEND:20231205T103000Z
DTSTAMP:20231205T043203Z
PRIORITY:5
TRANSP:OPAQUE
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SEQUENCE:0
LOCATION;LANGUAGE=en-US:https://some.random.url.com
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```